# Drive File Stream disc space

Tags: hard-drive, google-drive, google-drive-file-stream

I have installed on two computers the Drive File Stream, from Google. Theoretically, I have 1 Tb of disc space to save items on the cloud.

I'm using about 370 Gb of space, as it can be seen either from the browser (from the Drive/Gmail):

[image]

or from the properties of the My Drive folder:

[image]

The problem: the Google Drive File Stream drive (G:) is actually using a much bigger space. It is consuming almost 800 Gb of my HD (I leave all files to use offline, so Drive File Stream downloads all files to my computer). I don't understand why it consumes a much bigger space of my HD than what I'm using on the cloud. How do I correct it?

[image]

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1417936/google-drive-file-stream-cache-not-cleaning-up