# Backing Up Local Drive Image to Google Drive Without Cache Files

Tags: windows-10, disk-image, windows-backup, macrium, google-drive-for-desktop

I'm looking to store a backup image of my local disk onto Google Drive for Desktop (GDD) using Windows 10 without the files being first cached on the local drive. GDD has an assigned drive letter.

I created the local drive image using Macrium Reflect Free (MR), which splits the image file into a series of 4GB files and pointed the backup to the GDD drive letter.

Though the image files are uploaded onto GDD by pointing the backup destination to GDD's drive letter, GDD's cache raises my local drive's storage use from ~45% to ~85%, and then I have to [manually delete](https://superuser.com/questions/1417936/google-drive-file-stream-cache-not-cleaning-up) that cache.

Is there a method to backup an image of the local drive to Google Drive without creating cached files? Google support says it doesn't support FTP but third-party apps may achieve this.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Besides Google support, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Your prompt helped me discover many third-party apps that support FTP access to Google Drive, contrary to what the service provider's rep claimed.  Thanks.  The remaining issue is using Macrium to directly upload the backup via FTP, which I will figure out.